# Как сделать видимыми другие теги, когда тег canvas html 5 растянут на весь экран?

Tags: css, html5, canvas

Игра отрисовывается в canvas, для удобства есть кнопка сделать на весь экран

```
elementId.requestFullScreen() // и другие команды для кроссбраузерности.
```

Когда canvas не на весь экран, я могу по верх него отрисовывать кнопки и модальные окна тегами  т.к. их делать удобнее на html+css, чем делать велосипед на canvas. И это работает, пока я не нажимаю кнопку "сделать на весь экран".

Comment: Делайте полноэкранной не канву, а элемент в котором она и ваш интерфейс пользователя

Comment: @StrangerintheQ гениально, буду пробовать

Comment: оформил как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В Вашем случае полноэкранным необходимо делать не канву, а элемент в котором канва и Ваш UI.
2. Попробуйте готовое и лаконичное решение [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/), оно поможет вам не изобретать этот велосипед и сосредоточится на Вашей игре

Comment: Работает, все отлично, за библиотеку спасибо, а то мой велосипед на айфонах работать отказывался)

Comment: Рад помочь, обращайтесь)